# Loop Not Running When the Condition Has Been Met

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, while-loop

I am trying to implement input validation in the form on a while loop. When I enter a negative number for the midterm grade the program don't ask again. I've tried replacing the or with an and in the while again line but that still doesn't change the outcome. The input validation works for the while assessments line but not on the while again line. I believe the issue is with this piece of the code.

Edit:
When I enter a character other than N or Y the program prints the grade. The program should ask the user what grade the got on the midterm again.

```
def again():
    print ("again")
    again = 0
    while again != "Y" or again != "N":
        again = input("Do you want to calculate the grade again? Please enter either Y or N. ")
    if again == "Y":
        main()
```

The whole code is posted below for context.

```
import sys
def main():
    #Get the name and # of assessments
    named = ("name")
    un = name(named)
    tp = 0
    s= 0
    assessments = 0
    while assessments <= 0:
        assessments = int(input("how many assessments have you completed?"))


    #Get the total of assessments including homework
    for x in range(1,assessments + 1):
        g = float(input("grade of assessment"))
        tp += g

    scoree = tp / assessments
    finalG= finals(scoree)
    scoring(finalG)
    p(un)
    again()


def scoring(score):

    if score >= 97:
        print("You have an A+ in the class!")
        print ("Your grade as a percentage is:", score, "%",sep="") #Print the percentage
        sys.exit()
    if score >= 93 and score <= 96.9:
        print("You have an A in the class!")
        print("Your grade as a percentage is:", score,"%",sep="")
        sys.exit()
    if score >= 90 and score <= 92.9:
        print("You have an A- in the class!")
        print("Your grade as a percentage is:", score,"%",sep="")
        sys.exit()
    if score >= 87 and score <= 89.9:
        print("You have an B+ in the class!")
        print("Your grade as a percentage is:", score,"%",sep="")
        sys.exit()
    if score >= 83 and score <= 86.9:
        print("You have an B in the class!")
        print("Your grade as a percentage is:", score,"%",sep="")
        sys.exit()
    if score >= 80 and score <= 82.9:
        print("You have an B= in the class!")
        print("Your grade as a percentage is:", score,"%",sep="")
        sys.exit()
    if score >= 77 and score <= 79.9:
        print("You have an C+ in the class!")
        print("Your grade as a percentage is:", score,"%",sep="")
        sys.exit()
    if score >= 73 and score <= 76.9:
        print("You have an C in the class!")
        print("Your grade as a percentage is:", score,"%",sep="")
        sys.exit()
    if score >= 70 and score <= 72.9:
        print("You have an C= in the class!")
        print("Your grade as a percentage is:", score,"%",sep="")
        sys.exit()
    if score >= 67 and score <= 69.9:
        print("You have an D+ in the class!")
        print("Your grade as a percentage is:", score,"%",sep="")
        sys.exit()
    if score >= 63 and score <= 66.9:
        print("You have an D in the class!")
        print("Your grade as a percentage is:", score,"%",sep="")
        sys.exit()
    elif score >= 60 and score <= 62.9:
        print("You have an D- in the class!")
        print("Your grade as a percentage is:", score,"%",sep="")
        sys.exit()
    else: 
        print("You have an F")
        print("Your grade as a percentage is:", score,"%",sep="")


#ask for their name with "input"
def name(names):
    names = input("Could you please tell me what is your name?:")
    return names

    #Print the grade of the student with the name of the student in the same function
def p(p2):
    print("is your current average is",p2)

# asks if the use wants to run the program again?
def again():
    print ("again")
    again = 0
    while again != "Y" or again != "N":
        again = input("Do you want to calculate the grade again? Please enter either Y or N. ")
    if again == "Y":
        main()
#ask the user their final grades and adds it to the calculation
def finals(fgrade):
    mtg = 0
    ma = input("Did you take your midterm? Like before please enter either Y or N")
    if ma == "Y":
        while mtg <= 0:
            mtg = float(input("what is the midterm grade you got back?"))
        fgrade = mtg * .2 + fgrade *.8
    return fgrade

    if ma == "N":
        return fgrade
main()
```

Comment: This isn't a big issue but when you have a function that just gets an input from stdin and returns it, there's no real point of having it. Just makes it harder to follow the code...

Comment: @pizzastaticvoidmain  Yea, it's because there's no exit out of the loop unless you *want* to calculate the grade again.

Comment: The issue comes when you try and enter a negative number for the midterm grade.

Answer (score 2):

Because you're using the `or` conditional, the loop will repeat unless `again` is equal to "Y" *and* is equal to "N", which is impossible. Using the `and` conditional should solve the problem:

```
def again():
    print ("again")
    again = 0
    while again != "Y" and again != "N": #Notice the "and" rather than the "or"
        again = input("Do you want to calculate the grade again? Please enter either Y or N. ")
    if again == "Y":
        main()
```

The loop will now exit if `again` does not equal "Y" *and* `again` does not equal "N", which is what you want.

Comment: `again not in ("Y", "N")`

Comment: `while again != "Y" or again != "N":` Is there a name for this specific sort of error?  It pops up in novice code fairly often.